# Execute Powershell in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, asp.net-identity

Do any out there know how to Execute Powershell code on ASP MVC 5? Or maybe some link to a guide.

I know this guide but the writter use ASP Web Form, I'm new using MVC (actually ASP in general) so is kind of hard to transalte the stuff.

Guide: http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142

Answer (score 0):

This article tells pretty much everything.

If you are unfamiliar with ASP.NET MVC, I'd advise you to go [through the basics](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) first. Then everything should become way clearer.

Instead of using `ExecuteCode_Click` to execute your script, you need to create a *controller* and some *action* in it and put the code in there. 
Action should accept a string value with your script, do the processing, and return the result a `ViewResult` with script result as a property on your model.

The view could then render the result as you see fit (eg. inside an HTML textbox).